# Problema al realizar un PostRequest sobre una entidad con relaciones(Java Spring boot)

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, gradle, postman

cordial saludo a toda la comunidad.

Me encuentro realizando un CRUD con JPA en Java con spring boot, utilizo Lombok para generar los métodos en mis clases, tengo ya dos clases adicionales "Banks" y "Companies", en estas funcionan los request sin problemas, hago get y post sin inconvenientes pero al intentar realizar un post en el repositorio para CompanyBanks con postman, me tira un error diciendome que es una bad request, les voy a adjuntar el codigo, espero puedan ayudarme, muchas gracias. pd: tengo un get en la misma clase y si me funciona.

**Clase CompanyBanks.java**

```
package co.com.fuentech.fuentechappv2.entity;

import lombok.*;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Table(name = "company_banks")
public class CompanyBanks {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true)
    private Long id;
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_company", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Companies idCompany;
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_bank", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Banks idBank;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "status")
    private int status;
}
```

**Clase CompanyBanksModel.java**

```
package co.com.fuentech.fuentechappv2.models;

import co.com.fuentech.fuentechappv2.entity.Banks;
import co.com.fuentech.fuentechappv2.entity.Companies;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class CompanyBanksModel {
    private Long id;
    private Companies idCompany;
    private Banks idBank;
    private int status;
}
```

**Clase CompanyBanksMapper.java**

```
package co.com.fuentech.fuentechappv2.mapper;

import co.com.fuentech.fuentechappv2.entity.CompanyBanks;
import co.com.fuentech.fuentechappv2.models.CompanyBanksModel;
import org.mapstruct.Mapper;

@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface CompanyBanksMapper {
    CompanyBanks toCompanyBanks(CompanyBanksModel companyBanksModel);

    CompanyBanksModel toCompanyBanksModel(CompanyBanks companyBanks);
}
```

**clase CompanyBanksRepository.java**

```
package co.com.fuentech.fuentechappv2.repositories;

import co.com.fuentech.fuentechappv2.entity.CompanyBanks;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface CompanyBanksRepository extends JpaRepository<CompanyBanks, Long> {
}
```

**Clase CompanyBanksService.java**

```
package co.com.fuentech.fuentechappv2.services;

import co.com.fuentech.fuentechappv2.entity.CompanyBanks;
import co.com.fuentech.fuentechappv2.mapper.CompanyBanksMapper;
import co.com.fuentech.fuentechappv2.models.CompanyBanksModel;
import co.com.fuentech.fuentechappv2.repositories.CompanyBanksRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.ArrayList;

@Service
public class CompanyBanksService {
    private final CompanyBanksRepository companyBanksRepository;
    private final CompanyBanksMapper companyBanksMapper;

    @Autowired
    public CompanyBanksService(CompanyBanksRepository companyBankRepository, CompanyBanksMapper companyBanksMapper) {
        this.companyBanksRepository = companyBankRepository;
        this.companyBanksMapper = companyBanksMapper;
    }

    public ArrayList<CompanyBanksModel> getCompanyBanks() {
        ArrayList<CompanyBanks> companyBanksArrayList = (ArrayList<CompanyBanks>) companyBanksRepository.findAll();
        ArrayList<CompanyBanksModel> companyBanksModelArrayList = new ArrayList<>(companyBanksArrayList.size());
        for (CompanyBanks companyBanks : companyBanksArrayList) {
            companyBanksModelArrayList.add(companyBanksMapper.toCompanyBanksModel(companyBanks));
        }
        return companyBanksModelArrayList;
    }

    public CompanyBanksModel saveCompanyBanks(CompanyBanksModel companyBanksModel) {
        CompanyBanks companyBanks = companyBanksMapper.toCompanyBanks(companyBanksModel);
        return companyBanksMapper.toCompanyBanksModel(companyBanksRepository.save(companyBanks));
    }
}
```

**Clase CompanyBanksController.java**

```
package co.com.fuentech.fuentechappv2.controllers;

import co.com.fuentech.fuentechappv2.models.CompanyBanksModel;
import co.com.fuentech.fuentechappv2.services.CompanyBanksService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/companyBanks")
public class CompanyBanksController {
    @Autowired
    private CompanyBanksService companyBanksService;

    @GetMapping()
    public ArrayList<CompanyBanksModel> getCompanyBanks() {
        return companyBanksService.getCompanyBanks();
    }

    @PostMapping()
    public CompanyBanksModel saveCompanyBanks(@RequestBody CompanyBanksModel companyBanksModel) {
        return companyBanksService.saveCompanyBanks(companyBanksModel);
    }
}
```

**Aplicacion corriendo sin ningun error**
[image: pantallazo aplicacion java]

**Resultado de la solicitud en postman**
[image: Pantallazo Result Request postman]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El json que mandas en el request no es el correcto.

```
   @PostMapping()
    public CompanyBanksModel saveCompanyBanks(@RequestBody CompanyBanksModel companyBanksModel) {
        return companyBanksService.saveCompanyBanks(companyBanksModel);
    }
```

**CompanyBanksModel**  contiene los siguientes atributos:

```
    private Long id;
    private Companies idCompany;
    private Banks idBank;
    private int status;
```

Esto en json se debe reflejar de la siguiente manera:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "idCompany":{
     ...  //Aqui van los atributos de la clase Companies
   },
   "idBank":{
     ... //Aqui van los atibutos de la clase Banks
   },
    
   "status": 1

}
```

Los atributos tipo Objeto se representan con llaves {}

Por otro lado y como sugerencia revisa el path ya que no se si la url **localhost:1406/companyBanks** sea correcta, puedes revisar en el archivo de propiedades **application.properties** o **application.yml** por si se tiene declarado algun path.

Comment: Hola, yo modifique el puerto del server y estoy trabajando la app en local

Comment: amigo muchas gracias, si me sirvio.